# How to get high quality image from arcore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore

**I need high quality image with arcore. Currently I can extract the image but the armodel does not show.
I have tried to get the image from draw frame
**

Answer (score 0):

First get some supported camera configs and select one fitting you. For example highest width*height

```
val bestConfig = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(CameraConfigFilter(session)).maxByOrNull {
            it.imageSize.width * it.imageSize.height
        }
```

Then reconfigure ARCore session to use this camera configuration.

```
session.cameraConfig = bestConfig
```

Docs here: https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#setCameraConfig-cameraConfig